# Meu code shell script não lista todos os processos do usuario

Tags: linux, shell-script

Por que meu codigo não lista todos os processos do usuario?
fiz um script para eliminar processos de um usuario, é exercicio...
Bom básicamente fiz um whoami e adiquiri em uma variavel, depois disso fiz um
ps -aux | egrep $variavel , e ele retorna processos porém não retorna todos do usuario alguém sabe o porquê? Aqui vai o código, a parte do if comentada é para encerrar o processo com o nome dado, parece besta mas estou iniciando em shell script então não estou conseguindo

```
#!/bin/bash

variavel=`whoami`

ps -aux | egrep $variavel

echo "Digite o nome do processo que deseja matar: "

read nome

clear

for processo in $(ps -aux |egrep $variavel |xargs -n1)
do
# if [ $nome == $processo[9] ]; then
#killall $nome
# echo "Processo morto"
# fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa assim:

```
ps -fu $(whoami)
```

Leia mais sobre o `ps` [aqui](http://www.manpages.info/linux/ps.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar `ps auxf` ao invés de somente `ps aux`

O comando `ps auxf` geralmente mostra de todos usuários, inclusive não estando logado como `root`

Se quiser procurar processos de um determinado usuário pode fazer o seguinte:

```
ps auxf | grep "nomeDoUsuario"
```